# Set permissions based on another organisation's Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

Can you please tell me if this scenario (or something reasonably close to it) is possible, and if so, how?

Say I have a server on my network, and I want to grant access through Active Directory to some resources to users from another organisation's network (via site-to-site VPN, perhaps). The users granted access should be able to access the resources as if it were on their own network (so no extra logins, etc.)

Can this be done?

Thanks,
GA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming the other end is a separate Active Directory forest, what you want is to create a Trust relationship first between the two. This can be either **one way** or **two way** trust, and you need a whole bunch of ports open between the two LANs to allow the domains to talk to each other.

Then you can grant access to resources in your domain by adding foreign users/groups to your groups or ACLs.